# Going-up and going-down theorems: motivation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading about the going-up and going-down theorems in Atiyah & Macdonald's commutative algebra book.

I'm wondering if anyone could give me some basic facts/examples to help me understand why these two theorems are so important.

Neither of these theorems are actually used in Atiyah & Macdonald, and yet I don't find the statements to be so obviously remarkable that they should deserve a special name.

Comment: Well, if you want evidence, I typed the theorem number (5.11) in the search button on my pdf version, and nothing turns up aside from the statement of the theorem and an exercise!

Comment: Okay, well, it seems there's one application of 5.16 (going down) in the last chapter of A&M. But I think my question is still very legitimate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Algebraic geometry makes many facts like this more compelling.  For example, the going-up property for a ring map $R\to S$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Spec} S \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ being a closed map.  Also, if $R\to S$ has finite presentation and the going-down property, then $\operatorname{Spec} S \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is open.

So going-up is important in the study of proper morphisms (which are the algebraic geometry version of compact maps of topological spaces).  It is used in the proof that finite morphisms of schemes are proper.

Answer (score 9):

1) Suppose $A\subset B$ is an integral ring extension.
 Then the affine scheme $\text{Spec} (B)$ has the same Krull dimension as $\text{Spec} (A)$.
This results from the going-up theorem 5.11, the lying-over theorem 5.10 and the incomparability theorem 5.9

2) Does this situation arise in practice? You bet!
For example Noether's normalization theorem states that any finitely generated **algebra** $B$ over a field $k$ (which is not assumed algebraically closed) is an integral extension of a purely transcendental ring in $n$ indeterminates $A=k[t_1,\cdots,t_n]$, and is  thus a finitely generated **module** over $A$: cf. Remark page 60.
Geometrically this means that **any** affine variety $X$ of dimension $n$ over $k$ admits of a finite ramified covering $X\to\mathbb A^n_k$ onto affine $n$-space . What a wonderful  result!

Comment: Could you explain 'ramified covering?'

Comment: A ramified covering is a finite surjective morphism that needn't be étale (but definitions can differ). I didn't want to say something very precise but just convey the intuition  that (at least for $k=\mathbb C$) the morphism $X\to\mathbb A^n_k$ looks like a topological covering over a Zariski-open subset of affine space .